# redirect_to after failed validation possible in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, tdd

Here is my test:

```
def test_words_with_non_letters_are_rejected
    visit '/plays'
    click_link_or_button 'Play New Word'

    fill_in 'play[word]', :with => 'boom!'
    click_link_or_button 'Play!'
    assert page.has_css?("#errors")

    fill_in 'play[word]', :with => '37nums'
    click_link_or_button 'Play!'
    assert page.has_css?("#errors")

    fill_in 'play[word]', :with => 'ok'
    click_link_or_button 'Play!'
    assert_equal '/plays', current_path
end
```

Here is my controller:

```
class PlaysController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @plays = Play.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    if params[:play][:word].blank?
      flash[:error] = 'blank'
      redirect_to new_play_path
    else
      @play = Play.create(plays_params)
      redirect_to plays_path
    end
  end

  private

  def plays_params
    params.require(:play).permit(:word)
  end
end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Play < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save { self.word = word.downcase }

  validates :word, presence: true, length: { maximum: 7 }
  # validates_format_of :word, :with => 

  def letter_scores
    {"A"=>1, "B"=>3, "C"=>3, "D"=>2, "E"=>1, "F"=>4, "G"=>2, "H"=>4, "I"=>1, "J"=>8,
     "K"=>5, "L"=>1, "M"=>3, "N"=>1, "O"=>1, "P"=>3, "Q"=>10, "R"=>1, "S"=>1, "T"=>1,
     "U"=>1, "V"=>4, "W"=>4, "X"=>8, "Y"=>4, "Z"=>10}
  end

  def score(setting_hash = {:word_multiplier => :single})
    word_multiplier = {:single => 1, :double => 2, :triple => 3}

    word.upcase.chars.inject(0){|sum, letter| sum + letter_scores[letter]} * word_multiplier[setting_hash[:word_multiplier]]
  end
end
```

So I am having trouble writing the regex for the validates_format_of validation of the Play model. Also, I do not know how to redirect to the right page after a failed validation. I tried writing two redirect_to's in the create controller, but I got an error message of having too many redirect_tos.

In the else conditional of the create action, I tried writing this after the Play.create line:

```
redirect_to plays_path if @play
flash[:error] "Something when wrong during Play creation"
redirect_to new_play_path
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails prohibits you from using **render** or **redirect** more then once in the action. And these methods don't stop the execution flow so you're trying to execute them twice in your example. Instead you can **return** right after redirection. Like this

```
redirect_to plays_path and return if @play
```

And I would suggest to refactor **create** method this way

```
def create
  @play = Play.create(plays_params)
  if @play.save
    redirect_to plays_path
  else
    flash[:error] = @play.errors.full_messages
    redirect_to new_play_path 
  end
end
```

So you can get all your validation error messages in the flash. This is not the best way of using flash though, it is generally better to return specific messages. Like

```
flash[:error] = "Can't save play"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `create` method to:

```
  def create
    if params[:play][:word].blank?
      flash[:error] = 'blank'
      redirect_to new_play_path
    else
      @play = Play.new(plays_params)
      if @play.save
        redirect_to plays_path
      else
        flash[:error] "Something when wrong during Play creation"
        redirect_to new_play_path
      end
    end
  end
```